# Checking Most General Unifier

Tags: logic, unification

I've just taken a logic course in college. However, there's something that I'm still unsure about MGU. I will like to use an example to illustrate my query.

Suppose we have to unify $Q(y, G(A,z)), Q(G(x,B),y)$.

The MGU I got was $ x\leftarrow A, y \leftarrow G(x,B), z\leftarrow B$.

I am supposed to find another MGU (if it exists).

I gave the answer as $ x\leftarrow A, y \leftarrow G(A,z), z\leftarrow B$. Is this correct? Or is the MGU $ x\leftarrow A, y \leftarrow G(A,B), z\leftarrow B$?

Thank you.

Comment: The issue is that [substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)#First-order_term) must be *simultaneous*: this means that $y←G(x,B)$ will re-introduce an occurrence of $x$ that will not be affected by the simultaneous subst $x←A$.

Comment: That is, go with the second.  $(x,y,z)\gets (A,G(A,B), B)$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Can I clarify something about the simultaneous substitution? In the case of $y\leftarrow G(A,z)$, how am I violating the simultaneous substitution? Thank you.

Comment: Ref to subst $x←A,y←G(A,z),z←B$. If you apply it correctly (i.e. simultaneously) the result will be : $Q(G(A,z),G(A,B)),Q(G(A,B),G(A,z))$. No error here: is it the expected result ?

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @MauroALLEGRANZA 's comments.

> Suppose we have to unify $Q(y, G(A,z)), Q(G(x,B),y)$.
>
> The MGU I got was $ x\gets A, y \gets G(x,B), z\gets B$.

*Simultaneous* substitutions have to be applied *carefully* and *consistently* to always obtain a *sensible* result.   One must only substitute into the statement's pre-existing literals; please do *not* substitute into the literals of *other* substitutions being made *at the same time*.   (We want to avoid recursions, among other reasons.)

[ For example, applying $x\gets y, y\gets x$ *simultaneously* to $P(x,y,y,x)$ must give $P(y,x,x,y)$ ]

So your proposed substitution would obtain : $Q(G(x,B), G(A,B)), Q(G(A,B),G(x,B))$

$$Q(\underset{G(x,B)}{\underset{\uparrow}{y}}, G(A,\underset{B}{\underset{\uparrow}{z}})), Q(G(\underset{A}{\underset{\uparrow}{x}},B),\underset{G(x,B)}{\underset{\uparrow}{y}})$$

This is an *intermediate* result; the strings are still non-identical.   Now, applying the substitution $x\gets A$ *again* will make them identical.   However, we are required to do it all in one step.

Thus to *immediately* obtain the required result, you must make a *simultaneous* substitution of $x\gets A, y\gets G(A,B), z\gets B$.